# Monitor which process and which user modified a file

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

I'm trying to solve a problem where an xml file gets modified.
I want to determine which process and user is modifying this file.

I was thinking of more like using Powershell to subscribe to a file modified event. Once that event occurs, it triggers some code which outputs the details about the file modification (time, user, process etc.) to an output file.

I tried using the FileSystemWatcher, but it doesn't return required info about the user/process which modified the file so that wasn't sufficient for me.

Does there exist such an event class which I could subscribe to which will trigger an event when the file gets modified and also return which user or process modified the file and when.

If nothing works, the last resort is using the Windows Security Audit Logs which generates events when the file was modified and I can use powershell to parse them.

Thank you!

Comment: I think a combination of FileSystemWatcher and having the proper auditing set up on the file/folders to check the event log are about as good as your going to get to seeing who updated a file or folder.

Comment: Do you have any way to know when the file would get modified?  If you did, check into scripting ProcMon and that might get you some answers.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher won't give you the information you need. You can either create a filesystem filter driver or use our CallbackFilter product (it includes a pre-created filter driver) to track file operations and inspect from where they originate.